# Is there any way to snap a face of object to other face of other object without addon?

Tags: snapping

[image][image]

I tried to snap red face to blue face without addon but failed. Is there any way for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using an empty:

- Create an 'arrows' empty (arrows will show objects orientation)
- Set snapping option to face, this way:

[image]

- Snap the empty to the red surface:

[image]

- Parent the cylinder to the empty (select the cylinder then select the empty and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>
- Move the empty to the blue surface:

[image]

Orientation of the cylinder is inverted, so rotate the empty using **local** coordinates around Y with 180°: <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>180</kbd>

[image]

- Select the cylinder
- Clear parent using <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> and choose "clear and keep transformation"

Comment: thank you for answer. do you know any add on for snapping(or aligning) faces in Blender for easy work?

Comment: I don't know these addons but you can google "blender snapping addon" to find some, it seems.

Comment: ok. have a nice day